# How do you revoke access to system UDFs in Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Recently, I've come across a need to revoke the default access that new users get to various `PUBLIC` objects.  Revoking access to most things is pretty straightforward:

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC CASCADE;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA information_schema FROM PUBLIC CASCADE;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA pg_internal FROM PUBLIC CASCADE;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA pg_catalog FROM PUBLIC CASCADE;
```

This does not, however, cover functions. Specifically, I would like to deny access to [System Administration Functions and System Information Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_SQL_functions.html).  One could argue that these should not be visible by default, but that's another topic entirely.

There are two parts to my question:

1. Is there a simple way to revoke access to all of these functions at once rather than individually?
2. When revoking access to individual functions, why can't I resolve the signatures for functions that use `text` arguments?

### Part 1

According to what I've researched, the answer to the first part of my question appears to be *no*, that you must revoke access to functions individually.  And by individually, that means revoking access to individual function signatures as can be obtained from the query

```
select oid, oidvectortypes(proargtypes), * from pg_proc proc
where proc.proname ilike '%<function_name>%';
```

This yields a list like this:

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTION CURRENT_SETTING(text) FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTION PG_CANCEL_BACKEND(int) FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTION PG_TERMINATE_BACKEND(int) FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTION SET_CONFIG(text, text, boolean) FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTION CURRENT_DATABASE() FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTION CURRENT_SCHEMA() FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTION CURRENT_SCHEMAS(bool) FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTION "CURRENT_USER"() FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTION "CURRENT_USER_ID"() FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTION HAS_DATABASE_PRIVILEGE(text, text) FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTION HAS_DATABASE_PRIVILEGE(oid, text) FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTION HAS_DATABASE_PRIVILEGE(name, text, text) FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTION HAS_DATABASE_PRIVILEGE(name, oid, text) FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTION HAS_DATABASE_PRIVILEGE(integer, text, text) FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTION HAS_DATABASE_PRIVILEGE(integer, oid, text) FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTION HAS_SCHEMA_PRIVILEGE(oid, text) FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTION HAS_SCHEMA_PRIVILEGE(name, text, text) FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTION HAS_SCHEMA_PRIVILEGE(name, oid, text) FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTION HAS_SCHEMA_PRIVILEGE(integer, text, text) FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTION HAS_SCHEMA_PRIVILEGE(integer, oid, text) FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTION HAS_SCHEMA_PRIVILEGE(text, text) FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTION HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(name, oid, text) FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTION HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(integer, text, text) FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTION HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(integer, oid, text) FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTION HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(text, text) FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTION HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(oid, text) FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTION HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(name, text, text) FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTION PG_BACKEND_PID() FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTION PG_GET_COLS(text) FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTION PG_GET_LATE_BINDING_VIEW_COLS() FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTION PG_LAST_COPY_COUNT() FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTION PG_LAST_COPY_ID() FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTION PG_LAST_QUERY_ID() FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTION PG_LAST_UNLOAD_COUNT() FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTION "SESSION_USER"() FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTION SLICE_NUM() FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTION VERSION() FROM PUBLIC;
```

**Question**: Is there a simpler approach?

### Part 2

The manual approach is verbose, but it should work, right?  Well, not exactly.  If you run this in Redshift, the revoke statements that contain function signatures with `text` will fail.  For example,

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTION CURRENT_SETTING(text) FROM PUBLIC;
```

yields an error

```
ERROR:  function current_setting(character varying) does not exist
```

After investigating this further, I became convinced this was an unintended side effect of [Redshift's character conversion rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Character_types.html#r_Character_types-varchar-or-character-varying), specifically the rule that converts `text` to `varchar`.

This is illustrated by creating a test function like so:

```
create function test_udf (text, text)
  returns numeric
stable
as $$
  select case when $1 > $2 then 1.0
    else 2.0
  end
$$ language sql;
```

The resulting function's signature is reported as

```
test_udf(character varying, character varying)
```

**Question**: The fact that I can't properly revoke access to system functions whose signatures involve `text` arguments appears to be a bug in Redshift.  Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure the high level system function like `pg_terminate_backend` can be executed by new users by default? have you tried testing this? I haven't but I'm quite sure you can't run them by default, otherwise it would be a serious design oversight. (upd: looked at your comment in the post)
As for `text` arguments, it's translated to `varchar` because there is no `text` data type in Redshift

Comment: @AlexYes - I have not tested every function exhaustively, no.  My approach has been to assume the worst.  To answer your question though, it appears there is a built-in check for `pg_terminate_backend` (possibly superuser?) that prevents the function from doing anything harmful when run.  Re: the translation, yes I know that there is no `text` datatype, however the system tables contain registered function signatures with that nonexistent type - the crux of the second part of my question.  It appears impossible to revoke access due to this bookkeeping issue.